# While loop to update game engine blocks node event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, game-engine, event-loop

I am building a multiplayer game using Node.js. To continuously update the state of all games, I do the following

```
while (true) {
  for (const game of games) {
    game.update()
  }
}
```

This apparently results in the node event loop being blocked. What is the proper technique here?

The game is real-time and so needs to be continuously updated.

Comment: https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/understanding-setimmediate/

Comment: What exactly are the real-time requirements of your game? Is it hard or soft realtime? How many updates per second do you *need*?

Comment: to determine the best answer it can depend on what you actually do in `game.update()`

Comment: Instead of `while (true)`, could you do `var upd = function() { for (const game of games) { game.update(); } setTimeout(upd, howOften); }; upd();`?  Using `setTimeout` makes the recursive function **asynchronous** (nonblocking), whereas a `while (true)` loop is **synchronous** (i.e. blocking).  Here is the documentation on `setTimeout`:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Sounds like [gamedev.se](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com) would be a better fit for that question. They actually already have an almost dupe: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61642/physics-loop-in-a-nodejs-socket-io-environment

Answer (score 1):

This way, all code will be run in the main thread, so if you create a while loop with true, it will completely block the main thread. The simple approach is to invoke the update function X times per second. One way to accomplish this is:

```
  const FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 20;
    const REFRESH_TIME = 1000/FRAMES_PER_SECOND;
    
    setTimeout(updateGames, REFRESH_TIME):
    
    function updateGames()
    {
      for (const game of games) {
        game.update()
      }
    }
```

This approach should work, but note that it doesn't scale well for multiple games because if the processing time exceeds the allotted time for a frame, it will lock up the entire application.

Another way to solve this is by using [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). You can use a pool of workers or even one worker per game.

Using one Web Worker to all games, you can do this:

**main.js**

```
// Create a new web worker
const worker = new Worker('worker.js');

// Add an event listener to receive messages from the worker
worker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  const { games } = event.data;
  console.log('Received updated games from worker:', games);
});

// Function to send a message to the worker to update the games
function updateGames() {
  worker.postMessage('updateGames');
}

// Set a timer to periodically update the games
setInterval(updateGames, REFRESH_TIME);
```

**worker.js**

```
// Initialize the games array
const games = [];

// Function to update the games
function updateGames() {
  for (const game of games) {
    game.update();
  }

  // Send the updated games back to the main script
  self.postMessage({ games });
}

// Event listener to receive messages from the main script
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  const message = event.data;

  if (message === 'updateGames') {
    updateGames();
  }
});
```

A bether aprouch is using one pool of workers, where each worker update one single game.